# Send Data to and from applications on a network (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, communication

I'm trying to create a Siri like program, where I send text data from a client to a server, which allows the client to pass functions and set conditions within an application on the server machine.

This is my first networked based project, and have never really tried anything like it, so am a little intimidated by ports and protocols and the alike. 
I find there's tons of information on remote file administration (SSH) and remote desktop connections etc... however there is a minimal amount of information based upon application communication.

I'd imagine I'll have to use some type of remote procedure call and pass as an exponent of a function, but I'm not entirely sure.

I'm not looking for a direct answer about the whole networking side of Ubuntu Linux - just a point to the right direction.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out thrift I think that's what you're looking for